# How to Assign a Enum Value to a String Variable

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, enums

Having an enum like this:

```
enum Items { one, two, three, four};
```

How can I assign result to a string variable like

```
string itemType = Items.2;
```

or

```
string itemType = Items.one;
```

Can you please let me know if it is possible or not? Thanks

Comment: `Items.one.ToString()`?

Comment: Do you want the string name "one" or the underlying numeric value "1"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Enum.GetName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
var name = Enum.GetName(typeof (Items), Items.one);
```

Or:

```
var name = Enum.GetName(typeof (Items), 0);
```

Comment: This is definitely the better solution because you can go backwards with a similar syntax: `Enum.Parse(typeof(Items), name)`

Answer (score 1):

Add `.ToString() to your code:

```
string itemType = Items.one.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `ToString()` on the enum. You should be able to do `Items.one.ToString()` and get the string representation of the enum.